# How to pass crt and key files in .net framework version4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

How to pass .crt and .key files with httpclient .net framework version4.6.1

```
        var privatekey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(keyPath);
        byte[] keyBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(keyPath);
        var t1 = new X509Certificate2(certificateionPath);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rSACryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rSACryptoServiceProvider.(keyBytes);
        t1.CopyWithPrivateKey(rSACryptoServiceProvider);
```

so can anyone has already experienced with the above files...

Comment: You need to use HttpClientHandler to configure HttpClient to use a specific certificate. When working with HttpClient, it is important to use the HttpClientHandler because it provides a way to configure various aspects of HTTP request and response handling.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the HttpClientHandler class and configure it with the necessary client certificate.

Load the .crt and .key files into X509Certificate2 objects:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

var certPath = "path/to/certificate.crt";
var keyPath = "path/to/privatekey.key";
var cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath);
cert.PrivateKey = LoadPrivateKey(keyPath); // Implement the method to load the private key from the .key file
```

Then create an HttpClientHandler and set the client certificate:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```

Now create the HttpClient and use the HttpClientHandler:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    // Use the httpClient to send requests
}
```